# Problems using mpl::if_, boost::function, and a typedef to void

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, boost-function, boost-mpl

I'm new to the Boost.MPL library, and have some "beginners-problems"

Look at this sample:

```
template < typename F >
struct A {
   typedef boost::function_types::parameter_types<F> P;
   typedef typename boost::function_types::result_type<F>::type R;

   typedef typename boost::mpl::if_< boost::is_same< R, void >,
                                     boost::function< void ( void ) > ,
                                     boost::function< void ( R ) > >::type TTT;
   A() { }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
   A<int(int, float)>  ok; // working
   A<void(int, float)> compile_error; // non-working

   return 0;
}
```

When compiling I get:

```
xxx.cxx: In instantiation of ‘A<void(int, float)>’:
xxx.cxx:108:25:   instantiated from here
xxx.cxx:100:77: error: invalid parameter type
‘boost::mpl::aux::wrapped_type<boost::mpl::aux::type_wrapper<void>
>::type’
xxx.cxx:100:77: error: in declaration ‘A<F>::TTT’
```

What is the problem here, and how can I solve it?

To my understanding, only the selected part of `mpl::if_` should be evaluated by the compiler....

Comment: I get `'result_type' in namespace 'boost::function_types' does not name a type`

Comment: `P` is not used in `TTT` declaration, is it normal or is it a typo (we don't know what you are trying to achieve, so it is hard to tell)?

Comment: Why the downvote and the close vote? This is a perfectly reasonable question that can be answered and could help others. It made me learn that using a typedef to void in a parameter list is an error, which seems a sufficient justification for the question :). And it can help other people using MPL and/or `boost/std::function`. Perhaps the title could be rephrased since the issue is not so much about `function_types` but more about `function` and function signatures in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to explain the error, it should be noted that using a typedef to `void` in a parameter list is an error. These two GCC bug reports ([32058](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=32058) and [9278](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9278)) describe the problem, an point out that this is requirement from the standard.

So basically, according to §8.3.5/2 of the standard, this is legal:

```
void foo(void);
```

while this is not:

```
typedef void type;
void foo(type);
```

This explains why you needed the `if_` in the first place. Now to explain why you still have the error, you need to understand that lazy evaluation in MPL only apply to metafunctions: as long as you don't access the `type` inside a metafunction, it is not evaluated. Here, the `if_`'s arguments are not *evaluated* (they could not since they are not metafunctions), but that does not mean that they are not instantiated.

To overcome this issue, you could embed the `function` instantiations into metafunctions that could be lazily evaluated:

```
template < typename R, typename P >
struct get_function
{
  typedef boost::function< R (P) > type;
};

template < typename F >
struct A {
    typedef boost::function_types::parameter_types<F> P;
    typedef typename boost::function_types::result_type<F>::type R;

    typedef typename 
        boost::mpl::if_< 
            boost::is_same< R, void >,
            boost::mpl::identity< boost::function< void (void) > > ,
            get_function< void, R >
        >::type::type TTT;

    A() { }
};
```

This way, the erroneous `void (typedef_to_void)` never appears.

A better solution would even be to specialize the `get_function` metafunction for the `void` case:

```
template < typename R, typename P >
struct get_function
{
  typedef boost::function< R (P) > type;
};

template < typename R >
struct get_function< R, void >
{
    typedef boost::function< R (void) > type;
};

template < typename F >
struct A {
    typedef boost::function_types::parameter_types<F> P;
    typedef typename boost::function_types::result_type<F>::type R;

    typedef typename get_function< void, R >::type TTT;

    A() { }
};
```

No more `if_` needed!